# SFTP using system( ) call

Tags: c, sftp, return-value, system-calls

I am using system( ) call in C to make an SFTP file transfer:

```
int sftpFile()
{
  char cmd[256] = "echo put /home/file1.txt /home/file2.txt | sftp -F /dev/null -P 22022 -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no admin@10.113.21.89 > /dev/null 2>&1";
  
  int status = system(cmd);
  
  if (WIFEXITED(status)){
      int exit_code = WEXITSTATUS(status);
      printf("exit_code: %d"exit_code);
      return -1;
  }

  if (status == -1)
    return -1;

  return 0;

}
```

Two things:

1. Despite redirecting stdout and stderr to /dev/null, I still see output printed on the terminal when I run my app

```
/var/uf/sftpApp 
Warning: Permanently added '[10.113.21.89]:22022' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Connected to 10.113.21.89.
sftp> put /home/file1.txt /home/file2.txt
Uploading /home/file1.txt to /home/file2.txt
Couldn't write to remote file "/home/file2.txt": Failure
```

2. When sftp fails, system() and exit_code do not indicate any error. I expect them to return -1 but return value is 0.

Comment: Having written the actual code for fully automated sftp uploads at work, and having found all the race conditions involved, I can say that making this work is far too broad a question to ask on this site. If you have working in C in less than a thousand lines you probably missed something.

Comment: Does your sftp have `-b` (batch mode, see `man sftp`)? That might have some or all of the desired effects.

Comment: You get no error because the failure happens inside the sftp command. When sftp command exit it is always success. You should try using sftp with input file and output path as parameters or use scp.

Comment: the posted code seems to be missing a comma `,`  before the variable `exit_code`